# iOS App for LCD display through Arduino and BLE Shield

Tags: ios, iphone, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, lcd

I am trying to make an iPhone App that can text to an Arduino via BLE Shield, and then display the text on a LCD.

I looked at the BLE chat sample from RBL but I didn't seem like what I need.

I also tested the example of liquidcrystal from Arduino website and I was able to put text on a LCD buy using the serial monitor.

However, I had trouble using my iPhone App instead of the Serial Monitor to put text on the LCD.

Any ideas? Some coding example will be really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Which BLE shield are you using?  You can't use a serial port profile with BLE on iOS - you will need to write the data to characteristics on the BLE shield which it will then pass through to the serial port on the arduino.

Comment: Please complete your question with @paulw11's suggestions!

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for your reply. I am using the Shield from RedBearLab. I knew that I have to write the data on the Shield. I am having trouble about coding on both Xcode and the Arduino sketch, since I don't have very much coding knowledge.